# Can I look up attributes of a parent resources in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Context: I'm working on a new TF Provider using [SDKv2](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/sdkv2).

Let's assume there're 3 resources ("org", "department", "team" resources that references each other by ID):

```
resource "org" "foo" {
   name   = "abc"
   height = "5"
}

resource "department" "bar" {
   org_id = org.foo.id
   name   = "xyz"
   weight = "5"
}

resource "team" "qqq" {
   org_id = org.foo.id
   department_id = department.foo.id
   age = "10"
}
```

The current setup has been working fine for us but now we're looking at adding another `employee` resource that would have to reference all other 3 resources.

```
resource "employee" "abc" {
   org_id = org.foo.id
   department_id = department.foo.id
   team_id = team.qqq.id
   name = "abc"
   org_name = org.foo.name
}
```

and what's even worse, they need to reference `org.name` so we figured there're too many references.

Is there a way we could iterate through TF state programmatically or something that would allow us to reference just `team.qqq` and infer all these `org_id`, `department_id` etc?

```
resource "employee" "abc" {
   team_id = team.qqq.id # somehow iterate over TF state, find team.qqq.id = team_id and infer org_id and department_id
   name = "abc"
}
```

Comment: I don't see the `too many references` ... that code looks good for terraform standards, see this example: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_record#alias-record ... we can see it has `aws_elb.main` for two attributes is that too many references?

Comment: You could do this with a `Map` type in Go to only supply one argument value, but it may be awkward to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

Your code looks good to me I've seen worst...
I really don't see the too many references, see this example:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_record#alias-record

```txt
resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id
  name    = "example.com"
  type    = "A"

  alias {
    name                   = aws_elb.main.dns_name
    zone_id                = aws_elb.main.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```

... quite common to see that

---

Honestly I share your pain, those of us used to object oriented programming are furious with terraform, ideally we pass a reference to the entire object and let the resource use what it needs, if I was to architect it, resulting code could look something like:

```txt
resource "org" "foo" {
   name   = "abc"
   height = "5"
}

resource "department" "bar" {
   org    = org.foo
   name   = "xyz"
   weight = "5"
}

resource "team" "qqq" {
   department = department.bar
   age        = "10"
}

resource "employee" "abc" {
   team = team.qqq
   name = "abc"
}
```

and from the employees attributes we could know everything about org, department or team it belongs to:

- `employee.abc.team.department.org.name`
- `employee.abc.team.department.weight`
- `employee.abc.team.age`

But good luck implementing that in a TF Provider